# Pass username and password to Flask Oauth2 Server (password grant type)

Tags: python, authentication, flask, oauth-2.0, flask-oauthlib

I'm implementing Flask REST API with Flask-Oauthlib and wondering is it ok to pass username and password in URL parameters? For example:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&grant_type=password&username=myusername&password=hopeudontseemypass
```

In my development environment all the requests are showing in logs as plain text like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - "GET /api/token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&grant_type=password&username=myusername&password=hopeudontseemypass HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Is there any way to pass base64 encoded username/pass in request headers? All the password grant type examples are using username and password in URL parameters, so don't know is this a really problem if server will use SSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OAuth protocol spec says that the parameters must be POST-ed to the token endpoint. By accepting them as query parameters the Authorization Server violates the spec. Better use POST to avoid the credentials ending up in log files.

Comment: Great! thanks for your answer. Didn't notice that i was allowing GET... I changed this to POST but still getting username and password as plain text in HTTP request log.

Comment: have you removed the GET parameters after adding them to POST?

Comment: now i moved get parameters to post body and it works